# normalize values for imadjust

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to use `imadjust`, and in order to do that I have to normalize the values in my image (grayscale image) to 0~1. I have tried the following:

for getting min/max values:

```
minValue = min(I(:));
maxValue = max(I(:));
```

than I tried using `imadjust` in some ways:

```
Iadjusted = imadjust(I,[lowestValue/highestValue; highestValue/highestValue] ,[0 1]);
Iadjusted = imadjust(I,[lowestValue/255; highestValue/255] ,[]);
Iadjusted = imadjust(I,[double(lowestValue/highestValue); double(highestValue/highestValue)] ,[]);
```

but none of them worked. Each of them shows error/ shows the original image without any change. When I displayed min/max values the results were right, but when I am trying to display to normalization it always shows 0 or 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you need to use `imadjust` then as the manual tells you, use the following syntax: `Imadjusted = imadjust(I,[minValue; maxValue],[0; 1])` or `Imadjusted = imadjust(I,[minValue; maxValue],[])` as `[0; 1]` is the default.

Comment: You are simply using wrong command for normalization. imadjust is for intensity modification of an image to same type of image. So if you are trying what you are doing right now, you will have an image with 0 or 1 values. Simple im2double command would produce double-precision image whose pixels are between 0 and 1 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MATLAB images are stored using uint8 by default, therefore in [0 1] you can only have two integer number (i.e. 0 and 1). To do what you want between and get an image with range [0, 1] you have to use doubles.

Therefore if you want to use imadjust:

```
I = double(I)/255; 
J = imadjust(I,[min(I(:)); max(I(:))],[0.0; 1.0]);
```

(Imadjust with doubles wants everything to be between 0 and 1. This is true in general for images expressed with doubles).

Comment: I've made a mistake on the second part of the question that I did removed. The first part of the answer (the wanted one) still stand.

Answer (score 0):

This function adjusts a signal (can be image) to the range [0,1]

```
function normsig = normalize(sig)
   sig = double(sig);
   normsig = (sig-min(sig(:))) / (max(sig(:))-min(sig(:))) ;
end
```

usage for an image signal:

```
img = imread('xxxx.jpg','jpg');
figure; imshow(img);
normalizedimg = normalize(img);
figure; imshow(normalizedimg);
```